# rails, ruby, how to count and sort, display top results

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model, count

Think I have a simple question here:

I have a User Model, and a Post Model. Users has many posts, and posts belong to User. I want to count the total number of posts by user and display the top 10 users with the most posts. Here is the code I have so far:

controller:

```
@users = User.all
```

view:

```
<% @users.sort.each do |user| %>
    <%= user.username %>: <%= user.posts.count(:group => 'user_id') %><br>
<% end %>
```

This gets me the total posts per user, but sorts by username. I understand why this is happening, but not sure how I can change it to sort by the count instead. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First query the database like this:

```
@posts_per_user_count = Post.joins(:user).group(:user).order('count_all DESC').limit(10).count
```

This is going to result in a hash, which contains arrays with your result. Then in your view you can iterate over it like this:

```
<% @posts_per_user_count.each do |item| %>
    <%= item[0].username %>: <%= item[1].to_s %><br>
<% end %>
```

Please also see the answer from anonymousxxx. He is using the counter. This is more efficient than query the database in the way I do.

Comment: thanks robin - i like your answer. I tried it but it says that 'username' is an undefined method. how would i go about connecting item[0] to the user model? =/ thanks again

Comment: Can you send me the output of `Post.joins(:user).group(:user).order('count_all DESC').limit(10).count` in a gist or a pastbin? :-)

Comment: I forgot the `each` (edited it now) have you added the each to loop through?

Comment: Yeah - i caught the missed 'each' already. The output is a hash: {1=>6,2=>1}

Comment: Strange, I've tried it with a minimal example. Does your Post model have this `belongs_to :user`? Have you changed anything, do adapt it to your solution?

Comment: brilliant - it was my bad. i added an id when i wasn't supposed to. thanks for the solution, robin!

Answer (score 2):

Rails have `counter_cache` you can read point 4.1.2.3 on this guide [belongs_to Association Reference](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#belongs-to-association-reference) .

The first thing you should have a `posts_count` column on User model with `integer` data type and `0` default of value. After add `posts_count` column, add `counter_cache` to `Post.rb`

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user, :counter_cache => true
end
```

If you add a record to post including user, it can automatically add`1` value to `posts_count` attribute on User model. So if you want to display the top 10 users with the most posts. You can try this :

```
@user = User.find(:all, :limit => 10, :order=> 'posts_count desc')
```

---

Or another way to do that. Using [scopes](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#scopes)

You can add scope to your User model

```
Class User < ActiveRecord::Base
 scope :top_ten, select("users.id, other_attribute, count(posts.id) AS posts_count"). joins(:posts).group("users.id").order("posts_count DESC").limit(10)
end
```

And on your controller :

```
@user = User.top_ten
```

Comment: If you have existing User and Post records, don't forget to initialize the count values in your table. There is a sample for the migration script you will want here: http://www.elegantruby.com/Tutorials/2013/01/25/adding-a-counter-cache-for-fun-and-profit/

Comment: @kristinalim : oh I forgot for that, thanks for reminding me. Also you can do that via rails console `User.all.each { |user| User.reset_counters(user.id, :posts) }` after add `posts_count` column.