# How to get the highest association in a record

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I currently have a rails app that has a class Post. Post belongs_to Users.

How do you get the top 3 users that posts a lot? I'm guessing its somewhere

```
 Post.all.users.(do something here to get the user count and know who are the top 3
```

okay just an update as .all might be confusing. there are scenarios where I need to get the top user on a certain day so it would be like

```
Post.today.get_top_users
```

My question would be how to get the top users.

Comment: You might like this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/26542539/1942551

Comment: Hi @karlingen yeah I saw that a while ago, so I updated my question since mine wouldn't be getting the top user but for a specific date.

Answer (score 1):

I do it something like this.

`User.joins(:posts).select("COUNT(posts.id) as posts_count, users.*").group('users.id').order('posts_count DESC').where('Date(posts.created_at) = ?', Date.today).limit(3)`

Comment: Also `.limit(3)` and this is my fav

Comment: But I'll only be checking the post for a certain day so I need to specify for the date on post.

Answer (score 0):

Try this
**EDIT**

```
User.select('users.*, count(posts.id) AS posts_count').joins(:posts).where('posts.created_at = ?', Time.now).group('users.id').order('posts_count DESC').limit(3)
```

use `counter_cache` will be be faster. Define a class method 
add `counter_cache: true` to `model`

```
def self.get_top_users
    select('users.*, COUNT(posts.id) AS posts_count')
      joins(:users).where('posts.created_at = ?', Time.now).                                                  
      group('users.id').
      order('posts_count DESC').
      limit(5)
end
```

then you can call

```
Post.get_top_users
```