# Ruby on Rails: How to limit the results of sorting active record results

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have the following code, which sorts Users by number of posts. How can I limit this to the top 5 results?

```
<%= @top5 = User.all.sort{|a,b| a.questions.where(ques_num: 2).count <=> b.questions.where(ques_num: 2).count}.reverse %>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [rails, ruby, how to count and sort, display top results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26542223/rails-ruby-how-to-count-and-sort-display-top-results)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can simply add `.first(5)` or `.last(5).reverse`

```
<%= @top5 = User.all.sort{|a,b| a.questions.where(ques_num: 2).count <=> b.questions.where(ques_num: 2).count}.reverse.first(5) %>
```

or

```
<%= @top5 = User.all.sort{|a,b| a.questions.where(ques_num: 2).count <=> b.questions.where(ques_num: 2).count}.last(5).reverse %>
```